# Laravel showing product views based on categories

Tags: laravel

Here is my ShopController

```
        public function index()
    {
        if (request()->category) {
            $products = Product::with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function ($query) {
                $query->where('slug', request()->category);
            })->take(40)->paginate(9);
            

            $categories = Category::all();
        } else {
            $products = Product::inRandomOrder()->take(40)->paginate(9);
            $categories = Category::all();
        }

        return view('/pages/showroom')->with([
            'products' => $products,
            'categories' => $categories,
        ]); 
    }

    /**
     * Display a specified of the resource.
     *
     * @param string $slug
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     * 
     */
    public function show($slug)
    {
        $product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

        return view('/pages/product')->with('product', $product);
    }
}
```

What i should do to return different view based on specific category (not only one view per all categories)?

Answer (score 0):

if you have limitted number of categories you can create views based on your categories' name and return dynamic view instead of static view.

your view files structure could be something like this:

- pages

  - product

    - category-slug-1.blade.php
    - category-slug-2.blade.php
    - category-slug-3.blade.php

and then you should return view in your controller like this

```
return view('pages.product.' . $slug)->with('product', $product);
```